# Get screen size of multiple displays

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript, size, screen

For a small web app I need to get the screen size of multiple displays. First I tried it with simple javascript via `screen.height` but that only works for the primary display, no matter where the window was.

I was going to do a fallback with inputs anyways but i wanted an automatic way, too. I was looking for a way via actionscript but couldn't find anything.

I don't want something where the user has to click accept or anything like that. Just something that works without asking the user or when it doesn't using the fallback method (in this case just do nothing and let the user fill in the size himself)

Do you know any method?

Greetings

Comment: What is meaning of "primary display"?